# Permutation module, need some clarifications.

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I am reading some notes that  concerns permutation modules, but inside there is something I don't understand.

*Suppose $G$ acts on a set $X$ and denote $\mathbb{C}X$ the permutation module. It is said that given $x\in X$, $\operatorname{Orb}(x)$ is isomorphic as $G$-set to $G/H$ for some subgroup $H\le G$ and so $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$ is a direct summand of $\mathbb{C}X$, with character $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H1$ ($\operatorname{Ind}$ is the induction).*

What exactly is the action on $G/H$ for the isomorphism? What is the subgroup $H$ and why? Why does $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$ have character $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H$?

**Edit**

If this is the action, then taking $H=G_x$ (the stabilizer of $x$) then we have $orb(x)≅G/G_x$ (isomorphism of $G$-set). Then I know the orbits partition $X$, i.e. $X=orb(x_1)⊔…⊔orb(x_r)$ so we have $\mathbb{C}X=Corb(x_1)⊕…⊕Corb(x_r)≅C[G/Gx_1]⊕…⊕C[G/Gx_r]$ but then it seems to me that $Ind^G_H$ is a character of $G$. Why do they claim it is a character of $C[G/H]$?

Comment: I don't know who 'they' are, but I suspect they mean that it is the character of the representation on the cosets of $H$ in $G$, i.e., the character associated to that representation.

Answer (score 0):

The action of $G$ on $G/H$ is left multiplication (assuming the action of $G$ on $X$ is a left action). From here you should be able to work out the rest of your questions.

Comment: Okay. If this is the action, then taking $H=G_x$ (the stabilizer of $x$) then we have $\operatorname{orb}(x)\cong G/G_x$ (isomorphism of $G$-set). Then I know the orbits partition $X$, i.e. $X=\operatorname{orb}(x_1)\sqcup \ldots \sqcup \operatorname{orb}(x_r)$ so we have $\mathbb{C}X=\mathbb{C}\operatorname{orb}(x_1)\oplus \ldots \oplus \mathbb{C} \operatorname{orb}(x_r)\cong \mathbb{C}[G/G_{x_1}]\oplus \ldots \oplus \mathbb{C}[G/G_{x_r}]$ but then it seems to me that $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H$ is a character of $G$. Why do they claim it is a character of $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$?